# Print the first letter in the view but I don't need to repeat the letter

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm making a list of categories but I need the header to only show the first letter without repeating

This is for a list of all the categories of a store

Controller:

```
  def show
    @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @category_articles = @category.articles.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
  end
```

view:

```
<div class="container" id="tag-container">
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <section>
      <h2><%= category.name.first %></h2>
      <%= link_to "#{category.name}", category_path(category)%>
      <span>(<%= pluralize(category.articles.count,"")%>)</span>
  </section>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I'll really appreciate if you can help me with this.

Comment: Are categories sorted by name?

Comment: Yes they're, but the header is repeated, example:    A => arm,  A => Arc and i want something like this: A => arm,arc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing `categories` to be sorted by name, this can be an option. I'm using plain Ruby, but you can do the same with Rails. Consider `categories` array as the collection of records.

```
categories = %W(bat bet bot cat cut dot git got gut)

grouped_categories = categories.group_by { |w| w[0] }
```

Grouping by first letter (`{ |w| w[0] }`) using [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by). The method returns a Hash that you can iterate with nested loop:

```
grouped_categories
#=> {"b"=>["bat", "bet", "bot"], "c"=>["cat", "cut"], "d"=>["dot"], "g"=>["git", "got", "gut"]}

grouped_categories.each do |initial, vals|
  puts "-#{initial}"
  vals.each do |val|
    puts "----#{val}"
  end
end
```

It prints:

```
-b
----bat
----bet
----bot
-c
----cat
----cut
-d
----dot
-g
----git
----got
----gut
```

Comment: passing the code like this controller:     **@categories = Category.order(:name)
    @groups = @categories.group_by{ |w| w[0] }** and the view: **<% @groups.each do |initial, vals| %>
  <section>
      <h2><%= initial.name %></h2>
      <% vals.each do |category| %>
        <%= link_to "#{category.name}", category_path(category)%>
        <span>(<%= pluralize(category.articles.count,"")%>)</span>
      <% end %>
  </section>
  <% end %>** it say undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @JULIOMACHAN note that iGian is calling `group_by` on an _array of (string) names_. You are calling it on an _array of records_. If you used `@categories = Category.order(:name).pluck(:name)`  that would match iGian's code better

Comment: Or, you can keep you definition of `@categories` as you originally had it and use `.group_by { |category| category.name[0] }`

Comment: it work great using the second option that your recommended me

Answer (score 2):

If you wish the categories alphabetised,

```
categories = ["gut", "git", "bot", "cut", "got", "cat", "dot", "bet", "bat"] 

categories.sort.chunk { |w| w[0] }.each { |ltr,a| puts "#{ltr}: #{a.join(' ')}" }
b: bat bet bot
c: cat cut
d: dot
g: git got gut
```